# Do we need to take DB backup if we are using AWS RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a database hosted in RDS. The DB contains lots of very important data. We can't actually take a chance about the DB availability. Is there any chance that the data get lost for some reason?

I have seen about the AWS RDS service level agreement and its 99.95% availability. But what I need to check is, is it necessary to take a backup of the DB if the data is so important to us? Or will the AWS take care of that if the current DB is down or lost? Is there a way to recover the data?

Comment: If there's even a 0.000001% chance the data will lose, I would recommend backup the DB.

Answer (score 4):

AWS does automated backups automatically for your RDS data and Transaction logs.

However, you need to set the **retention period** (how long days you want AWS to retain old backups for?). Usual number is 14 days, but it is based on your business / data requirements.

On need basis, it is possible to recover to a point-in-time (up to the second accuracy) using CLI or APIs or via AWS Console. More on it [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PIT.html).

Though the SLA mentions **99.95%** availability, if you look at all previous years, RDS has been unavailable only in 2 instances (once in 2011 then in 2014). For a full list of AWS global outages, refer [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/technology/pes/).

Answer (score 0):

1) Amazon RDS creates and saves automated backups of your DB instance. Amazon RDS creates a storage volume snapshot of your DB instance, backing up the entire DB instance and not just individual databases.

2) Amazon RDS creates automated backups of your DB instance during the backup window of your DB instance. Amazon RDS saves the automated backups of your DB instance according to the backup retention period that you specify. If necessary, you can recover your database to any point in time during the backup retention period.

3) After you create a DB instance, you can modify the backup retention period. You can set the backup retention period to between 0 and 35 days. Setting the backup retention period to 0 disables automated backups

[User Guide for Automated Backups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithAutomatedBackups.html)

Backups incur costing based on the storage refer pricing page in below link

[RDS pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/pricing/)